# How to create table's td dynamically in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to create "tr" and '/tr' tags dynamically in angular using *ngFor. I have used the following code but its creating the following attached screen short table and showing tr tags as string. But i want to append these  tags in html. In addresses array i have the data for td's. so that's why i am running *ngFor for td's. Here i have to work with table only because i am working with print functionality using angular. I can create something like this using div's and bootstrap classes but my requirement is table only. I have to create tr on the basis of td's and in one tr i have to show 3 tds.

**For example i have 9 records in printAddresses then i want to print 3 rows and each row have 3 td's. If printAddresses  have 14 records then i want to print 5 rows and in the first 4 rows there will be records in all three td's and in 5th tr there will records in it's first 2 td's.**

[image]

in .ts file

```
tableRowStart = '<tr>';
tableRowEnd = '</tr>';
```

In .html file:

```
 <table class="row mb-5" style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody style="width: 100%;">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let address of printAddresses; let i = index">
        <ng-container *ngIf="i%3===0">
          {{ tableRowStart }}
        </ng-container>
        <td style="width: 30%">
          <div style="padding-bottom: 2%">
            {{ address.firstName }} {{ address.lastName }}
          </div>
          <div style="padding-bottom: 2%">
            {{ address.careOfAddress }} - {{ address.street}}
          </div>
          <div style="padding-bottom: 2%">
            {{ address.city }}
          </div>
          <div style="padding-bottom: 2%">
            {{ address.postalcode }} {{ address.state }}
          </div>
        </td>
        <ng-container *ngIf="i%3===2 || i===printAddresses.length-1">
          {{ tableRowEnd }}
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: @ritaj I know we can create rows dynamically but kindly read my requirements agains. I have to create tr on the basis of td and in one tr i have to show 3 tds.

Comment: @Manjit Can you show your expected output?

Comment: Regrettably there's no way to render opening & closing tags that way. Everything in between double curly braces will be: first evaluated, second rendered as a string. This is not PHP anymore mate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never try to append any HTML tag by storing them as a string. If required use DOM manipulations only.

Angular evaluates all expressions in double curly braces(interpolation binding), converts the expression results to strings.

We can create `<tr>` dynamically by iterating a list using `*ngFor` directive on `<tr>` tag or any HTML tag you want to generate dynamically.

This helps:

```
<tr *ngFor="let address of printAddresses; let i = index">
   <td> {{ address.firstName }} {{ address.lastName }} </td>
   <td> {{ address.city }} </td>
   <td> {{ address.postalcode }} {{ address.state }} </td>
<tr>
```

**Edit:**

For such a requirement, one of the approaches will be by splitting the `printAddresses` into a multidimensional array in your .ts file with 3 addresses in each inner array.

After splitting `printAddresses` looks like this: `[[addr1,addr2,addr3],[addr4,addr5,addr6]]`.

In .html file:

```
<tr *ngFor="let addressSet of printAddresses; let i = index">

   <td *ngFor="let address of addressSet ; >

      <div style="padding-bottom: 2%">
        {{ address.firstName }} {{ address.lastName }}
      </div>
      <div style="padding-bottom: 2%">
        {{ address.careOfAddress }} - {{ address.street}}
      </div>
      <div style="padding-bottom: 2%">
        {{ address.city }}
      </div>
      <div style="padding-bottom: 2%">
        {{ address.postalcode }} {{ address.state }}
      </div>

  </td>

<tr>
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your requirement properly, this will do,

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let address of printAddresses; let i = index">
            <td> {{ address.firstName }} {{ address.lastName }} </td>
            <td> {{ address.city }} </td>
            <td> {{ address.postalcode }} {{ address.state }} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Add additional styles based on your requirement.

For your exact requirement, I suggest grids and not tables. You can use bootstrap rows and columns like this :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4" *ngFor="let address of printAddresses">
        <div>{{ address.firstName }} {{ address.lastName }}</div>
        <div>{{ address.city }}</div>
        <div>{{ address.postalcode }} {{ address.state }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No,Its not fulfilling my requirements. For example i have 9 records in printAddresses then i want to print 3 rows and each row have 3 td's. If printAddresses  have 14 records then i want to print 5 rows and in the first 4 rows there will be records in all three td's and in 5th tr there will records in it's first 2 td's.

Comment: @Manjit, please extrapolate and deduct your needs from proposed response, the above answer satisfies your question. We're here to help others in the community, not resolve their work completely.

Comment: @Manjit As per your requirement you need to use rows and columns. Tables won't meet your needs like that.